# Inkwell onTap not working inside ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted my Card to be pressable so i first tried with ListTile onTap function then GestureDetector and lastly InkWell. Inkwell ripple effect is working but not onTap.

```
class Quizes extends StatelessWidget {
  const Quizes({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Quizes'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                return Card(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          print(position);
                        },
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text('Test ${position.toString()}'),
                        ),
                      )
                    ]
                  )
                );
              },
              itemCount: 1,
            ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  } 
}
```

Comment: if you use ListTile dont use Inkwell ListTile also tap

Comment: what error did you find? in my machine it's work perfectly

Comment: On my machine works aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to tell you it is working.

[image]

Same for ListTile, I just don't understand why you're putting a ListTile inside an InkWell it is a bit usless.

[image]

If you encouter troubles with your code try to hot reload or close your Android Studio and open it back or just update your flutter version. But if you have no errors it should work correctly.

Comment: thanks for quick reply, i think i am having some problem with the terminal, it was not showing anything at that time, now it is working fine.